# ffmpeg seeking to I-frame

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decoding

Is it possible to seek to a I-Frame using the av_seek_frame() function. 
The problem I am facing is that if I seek in a AVC file I get a lot of noise if I dont flush the buffer. And if I flush the buffer the decoder dose not return a frame until it comes across a I-Frame which causes problem in the calculation of total frames at the end of file if I am seeking.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide the flag AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY when calling av_seek_frame you will seek to key frames (I-Frames) only.
If you need more details on that function, consult the documentation [here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/functions.html#av_seek_frame).

Comment: Thanks for replyingI tried sending a '0' instead but it didnt help me. I am currently using ffmpeg-20140115-git-785dc14-win64.